# how can I allocate an array on the stack if the size is not known at compile time?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, stack, dynamic-memory-allocation, heap-memory

I'm writing a c++ program with visual studio and I have written this code

```
DWORD GetProcIDByName(const char* procName) {
    HANDLE hSnap;
    BOOL done;
    PROCESSENTRY32 procEntry;

    ZeroMemory(&procEntry, sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32));
    procEntry.dwSize = sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32);

    hSnap = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);
    done = Process32First(hSnap, &procEntry);
    do {
        /* here */ char file_str[sizeof(procEntry.szExeFile)];
        int wc_convert = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_ACP, 0, procEntry.szExeFile, sizeof(procEntry.szExeFile), file_str, sizeof(file_str), NULL, NULL);
        if (_strnicmp(file_str, procName, sizeof(file_str)) == 0) {
            return procEntry.th32ProcessID;
        }
    } while (Process32Next(hSnap, &procEntry));

    return 0;
}
```

in order to convert the value procEntry.szExeFile from a WCHAR* (wide unicode character array), to a standard char* to compare, I had to make a char* buffer for it. I wrote the line

```
char file_str[sizeof(procEntry.szExeFile)];
```

and realized later that I should use heap memory for this buffer that will change sizes depending on the process name, but I was surprised to see that my visual studio had no problem with this code and I was able to build it with no compiler errors. I haven't run it yet and I probably will not because I imagine if this runs there is a potential for buffer overflow and undefined behaviour

I don't have any issue, but I am curious about why I was able to write this code without getting a compiler error. If the process name is not known at compile time, how can I allocate this buffer on the stack?

Comment: The size is _not_ variable.  The `szExeFile` member is an array of size `MAX_PATH`.

Comment: @Dyskord https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/malloca?view=msvc-160 something like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `szExeFile` field is not dynamic length. It is a fixed-length array of `MAX_PATH` characters, holding a null-terminated string.

Note that:

- `sizeof()` reports a size in bytes
- `szExeFile` is an array of `wchar_t` characters, in your case
- `wchar_t` is 2 bytes in size on Windows.

So, when you declare your `char[]` array as `char file_str[sizeof(procEntry.szExeFile)];`, it will have a static compile-time size of `MAX_PATH*2` `char`s.  Which should be large enough to easily handle most conversions from `wchar_t[]` to `char[]` in this case.

BTW, your use of `sizeof(procEntry.szExeFile)` in the 4th parameter of `WideCharToMultiByte()` is wrong. That parameter expects a *character* count, not a *byte* count. Use `lstrlenW(procEntry.szExeFile)` or `wcslen(procEntry.szExeFile)` instead.  Or just -1 to let `WideCharToMultiByte()` count the wide characters for you.

That being said, an easier solution is to use `Process32FirstA()`/`Process32NextA()` instead. Or, change your function to take a Unicode `wchar_t` string as input. Either way, then you won't have to convert the `procEntry.szExeFile` at all, just use it as-is.

Also, you are leaking the `HANDLE` from `CreateToolhelp32Snapshot()`, you need to call `CloseHandle()` when you are done using it.

Try this:

```cpp
DWORD GetProcIDByName(const char* procName) {
    DWORD dwProcessID = 0;

    PROCESSENTRY32A procEntry = {};
    procEntry.dwSize = sizeof(procEntry);
   
    HANDLE hSnap = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);
    if (hSnap != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        BOOL ok = Process32FirstA(hSnap, &procEntry);
        while (ok) {
            if (_stricmp(procEntry.szExeFile, procName) == 0) {
                dwProcessID = procEntry.th32ProcessID;
                break;
            }
            ok = Process32NextA(hSnap, &procEntry);
        }
        CloseHandle(hSnap);
    }

    return dwProcessID;
}
```

Or this:

```cpp
DWORD GetProcIDByName(const wchar_t* procName) {
    DWORD dwProcessID = 0;

    PROCESSENTRY32W procEntry = {};
    procEntry.dwSize = sizeof(procEntry);
   
    HANDLE hSnap = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);
    if (hSnap != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        BOOL ok = Process32FirstW(hSnap, &procEntry);
        while (ok) {
            if (_wcsicmp(procEntry.szExeFile, procName) == 0) {
                dwProcessID = procEntry.th32ProcessID;
                break;
            }
            ok = Process32NextW(hSnap, &procEntry);
        }
        CloseHandle(hSnap);
    }

    return dwProcessID;
}
```

Comment: Amazing answer thank you so much. I would upvote this 100 times if I could. That makes a lot of sense. Also my finished program fails with a runtime error so perhaps the handle leak is part of the issue. Thank you!